# Concat all the files in a directory based on a column in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I currently have a few files in my directory and I would like to merge them based on a column.

I have currently managed to code the following out:

```
files = os.path.join(RunDir1, "FFU*.xlsx")

# List of merged files returned
files = glob.glob(files)
    
# Joining files with concat and read_excel
master_df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_excel, files), ignore_index=True)

master_df.to_excel("Compiled.xlsx",index=False)
```

However, my outcome will look something like this:
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXib2.png)

How can I edit my code such that if the product in Q4 exist in Q3, it will not create additional rows below with duplicated product name but instead, only add the data beside the Q3 column. Whereas if the product in Q4 does not exist in Q3, an additional row with the respective product will be added where the respective product for Q3 will be indicated as "0". Attached is the desired outcome. [Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pUpf.png)

Comment: Use `pd.merge` on `product` columns with `how='outer'`.

Comment: If i am not wrong, `pd.merge` requires comparison of two df, but i can have >2 files. How can i go about that?

Comment: Use `reduce` from `functools`